How to get a sticky Scrollbar in CSS / Javascript when scrolling inside nested divs
I have a table over which I need to be able to scroll vertically as a whole. (so with the scrollbar on the right, you scroll the left AND right column at the same time)
Inside this table there are 2 columns over which I need to be able to scroll horizontally (individually).
But the 2 horizontal scrollbars disappear at the bottom of the table because of the vertical scrollbar.
How do I get those to be visible at all times?
Here's the fiddle Example: Fiddle Example



#data {
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
}

#splitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: darkgrey;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  align-items:start;
}

#right-content {
  background: Gainsboro;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

#left-content {
  background: Gainsboro;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}
<div id="data">
  <div id="splitter">
    <div id="left-content">
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-content">
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Maybe something like this helps, if you try to run the code snippet below;


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }
body {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.myDiv {
  height: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: Gainsboro
}

span {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 150vh;
  display: block;
  background: darkgrey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="myDiv" id="left-content" style="width:20%" >
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <span>     
    </div>
    <div class="myDiv" id="right-content" style="width:30%">
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>    
      <span>     
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.myDiv');
    divs.forEach(div => div.addEventListener( 'scroll', e => {
    const offsetTop = div.scrollTop / (div.scrollHeight - div.clientHeight);
    const offsetLeft = div.scrollLeft / (div.scrollWidth - div.clientWidth);
    divs.forEach(d => {
       d.scrollTop = offsetTop * (d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight);
      d.scrollLeft = offsetLeft * (d.scrollWidth - d.clientWidth);
    });
  }) );
</script>
</body>
</html>




You can use like this


#data {
  background: grey;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
}

#splitter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: darkgrey;
  align-items:start;
  width:655px;
}

#right-content {
    background: Gainsboro;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 350px;
}

#left-content {
    background: Gainsboro;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width:180px;
    height: 350px;
}

div {
  margin: 10px;
}

p {
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}
<div id="data">
  <div id="splitter">
    <div id="left-content">
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
      <p>LeftColumnLeftColumn</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-content">
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>
      <p>RightColumnWithLongTextThatShouldBeScrollableHorizontally</p>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




not quite, the main-div needs to be scrollable as a whole. So if I scroll on the right, it scrolls both divs, left and right, at the same time.

you can check this now, I think it will help
